# ImportError: No module named android - Kivy Buildozer

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer

Buildozer successfully builds the app, but it fails on startup.

```
11-24 20:38:56.919 12128 12147 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Desktop/Hoto/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 17, in <module>
11-24 20:38:56.919 12128 12147 I python  :  ImportError: No module named android
11-24 20:38:56.949 12128 12147 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Buildozer.spec changes:

```
android.api = 28
android.minapi = 21
android.sdk = 24
android.ndk = 17c
p4a.branch = master
```

Has anyone ever had this problem? If yes, how do I solve it?

Full log and buildozer.spec https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/1492

Comment: Is that the main.py from your app? I don't know why buildozer would be attempting to run that.

Comment: @inclement Yes it is, adding `android` to the requirements in buildozer.spec fixes the problem but now `from kivy.utils import platform` imports an empty string, dropdown opens and closes immediately, `'TextInput' object has no attribute 'cursor_width'`, `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`...Most features are no longer working after the changes in buildozer.spec